# How to access an upstream Jenkins project $BUILD_LOG?

Tags: jenkins

I've created two Jenkins projects with the first (upstream) starting the second (downstream) as a Post-build Action - 'Parameterized build on other projects'.
[image]

The second project is parameterized with the same name as defined in the first project (I've also tried a String Parameter, instead of Text).
[image]

I need to access the upstream projects' ${BUILD_LOG} from the downstream project but, ${SB_LOG} always displays the downstream project ${BUILD_LOG}.

I'm using Jenkins ver. 1.646.
And I'm referencing ${SB_LOG} from a Post Build Action - 'Editable Email Notification', probably from the Email-ext plugin.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: did you ever find a solution to accessing the ${BUILD_LOG} ?

Comment: No I haven't :(